# print a for-loop in the console log inside an if-statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code, and the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrSwaggalicious/5XQE8/1/).

I can't make the code work and I think it is because the if-statement that includes a `for loop` inside.

How can I make the whole code work, I've tried it with 4 different code possibilities and none of them worked/

```
var commands = {
    'BOH': {
        text: 'BOH!',
    },
    'HALO': {
        text: 'HALO!',
    },
    'help()': {
        text: 'Please press F12 and see the value list.',
    },
};


$(".code").on("click", function () {
    var codePrompt = prompt("enter the value"),
    command = commands[codePrompt],
    alertMessage = "";
    consoleMessage = "Used '" + codePrompt + "' value.";
    if(!command) {
        alertMessage = "We are sorry but you entered a WRONG value.";
    } else {
        alertMessage = command.text;
    };
    if(command == 'help()') {
        for (key in commands){
            console.log(commands[key]);
            alertMessage = command.text;
        };
    };
alert(alertMessage);
console.log(consoleMessage);
});
```

Comment: Well, what do you want to happen?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about "how can I make the whole code works"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general cluelessness, debugging-slave request and 'cos I'm just 100% pissed off with deadbeat developers with the debugging skills of petrified goldfish.

Comment: @MarkGabriel I want to print on console log all the variables on `commands` variable.

Comment: Your loop never runs because the condition `command == 'help()'` is never true. You could replace it with `codePrompt == 'help()'`. You also need to rethink `alertMessage = command.text` which replaces the message on each iteration of the loop but never displays any of these messages.

Comment: @Stuart here we go!, now it works! thx Stuart and all the other mates that answuered my question, hope you have a nice day mates!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't this

```
if(command == 'help()') {
```

be

```
if(codePrompt == 'help()') {
```